# Akka Cluster - message coming from dead letters?

Tags: scala, akka, actor, dead-letter

I am using Akka Cluster and I have an interesting issue. I have one actor Actor1 on node A (akka.tcp://as@127.0.0.1:2554). This actor finds another actor on another node using

```
val actor2sel = context.actorSelection(RootActorPath(m.address) / "user" / "actor2")
```

where `m` is a member of the cluster. actor2sel is

```
ActorSelection[Anchor(akka.tcp://as@127.0.0.1:2553/), Path(/user/actor2)]
```

Later, Actor1 forwards a message to Actor2, which correctly gets the message, but the sender is deadLetters:

```
akka.tcp://as@127.0.0.1:2554/deadLetters
```

Do you have any pointer on what the cause might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forwarding a message only makes sense if there are at least three actors in the message chain:

```
actor1 --[sends Messsage1]--> actor2 --[forwards Message1]--> actor3
```

In `actor3`:

```
def receive = {
  case Message1 =>
    sender ! Response1
}
```

`sender` above is a reference to `actor1`, given the above message chain.

If there are only two actors involved, forwarding is not the right tool:

```
actor1 --[forwards Message1]--> actor2
```

In `actor2`, if it is forwarded a `Message1` from `actor1`, without a "previous" actor in the message chain, then the sender will be dead letters:

```
def receive = {
  case Message1 =>
    sender ! Response1
    // sender is dead letters if there are only two actors in the forwarding chain 
}
```

If Actor1 doesn't receive the message from another actor before forwarding that message to Actor2, simply have Actor1 send (`!`) the message to Actor2 instead of forwarding it.

If Actor1 does receive the message from another actor before forwarding it, ensure that this "previous" actor is running before Actor2 accesses `sender`.